# How do i change the colour of the bar graph?

Tags: python, matplotlib

My bar graph is set to the default colour of blue, so i would like to change it to orange colour. What changes do i need to make to my code, so that i can change my colour?

Here is my code:

```
trace2 =go.Bar(
x=['China','Hong Kong SAR','India','Indonesia','Japan','Malaysia','Phillpines','South Korea','Taiwan','Thailand','Vietnam'],
y=[4622347,1368789,2321576,5284928,2051699,2858926,1598839,114774,812080,1229608,1034688])

data = [trace2]
layout= dict(title='Total arrival counts from 2013 to 2015 for countries in Asia region by air', yaxis =dict(title='Arrival counts'),xaxis =dict(title='Countries'))
flg= go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
iplot(flg)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the color as RGBA to the `Bar` call:

```
go.Bar(x, y, color=(0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.6))
```

For Plotly you would have to use:

```
go.Bar(x, y, marker=dict(
        color='rgb(204,204,204)'))
```

Comment: Hi @Madeline if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.